# Нужна ли запятая перед уточнением (именем)?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

И как же вы познакомились с этим парнем(,) Джоном?

Имя в данном случае будет уточнением? Стоит его отделять запятой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну знакомец же не "парень Джон"! Может, кому и парень, а кому-то - лапонька Джоник. (Парень - это слегка сниженная лексика).

Стало быть, запятушка не просто нужна, но и необходима. Уточнение.